# Product activation in C++?

Tags: c++, security, activation

I am looking for a commercial-strength system that can provide me with product activation technology that is as convenient as possible for end users. Up until now I have been using the simplest system imaginable, where users get a key that is based on their name that they can use an unlimited number of times. This is more symbolic than anything else as users are able to pass their keys around freely, which they do. So I am wondering if there are any recommendations towards system that is well tested and widely used and works with C++ on Win32, but **not cracked**? I don't want to come up with a home made solution as I am no security expert, and do not have the time to learn the ins and outs of it.

Comment: "widely used, but not cracked" - not likely. Check out flexlm though.

Comment: Home-made solution has the advantage, that somebody will actually have to crack it, there's no existing generic crack available... Of course coming up with a decent system will require some effort... I'd concentrate more on the angle, that users are made aware when they are using it without valid license, and trying to make buying their own as easy as possible, and encourage them to do it. Remember, your actual goal is not to stop unlicensed use, your goal it to maximize revenue with minimal cost (in money or time).

Comment: Very valid points. I will certainly keep that angle in mind.

Comment: I don't know if this would work for you, but one time I did this and it seemed to work very well for me. I made a product with a simple system like you have, but I made it so I could give out a timed code that would expire after some set amount of time. That way, I could give out codes to reviewers or let people try it for a month or whatever. Then I made a web page that gave out a one-day code every day. Users could use the product as long as they wanted for free, but had to go to the web site to get the new code and enter it by hand. I sold more of that than any other product. YMMV.

Comment: @user1118321: Well, this is probably crackable, but the underlying idea is certainly appealing. A simple work-around would be to setup a virtual machine with a fixed date (since I suppose your product does not actually *need* to be connected to Internet ?). Was the key saved anywhere ? (to avoid having to re-enter it at each use) and was there a cool-down period on key retrieval ? (ie, apart from one-day keys, other keys require being authenticated and a single user may retrieve only one key per day to avoid sharing yet allow loss and replacement).

Comment: I saved the key in plain-text in the app's prefs. (No point in encrypting it since it was available on a public web site.) It was definitely crackable, and you could go to a bunch of trouble and waste a bunch of disk space with a virtual machine, but when you can go to the manufacturer's web page and get another one any day of the week, what's the point in even looking for a crack?